# How to set the rootViewController to point to the address of a pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, rootview

Summary: the rootViewController is set to a pointer. I change the pointer and rootViewController doesnt change.

I set my rootViewController set to a pointer to a view controller called 'currentViewController'.

change 'currentViewController' to point to a different UIViewController - and the iPhone/iPad doesn't update its screen. Why?

Side note the following does not work - it shows the view controller at index=0:

```
_currentViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = _currentViewController; 
_currentViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

side note the following does work, because it shows the viewcontroller at index 1, but does not make sense to me (I already told rootViewController the first time where it should point):

```
_currentViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = _currentViewController; 
_currentViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = _currentViewController;
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how pointers and assignment work. When you write:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = _currentViewController;
```

...what happens is that `rootViewController` now holds a value which is the address of some object in memory. Changing what `currentViewController` points to (i.e. changing its value) has no affect on `rootViewController`. It still points to whatever you told it to point to (i.e. its value doesn't change).

You're treating the assignment as though `rootViewController` becomes an alias for `_currentViewController`. This isn't what happens. What happens is that `rootViewController` is assigned a value. That's it. If you want it to have some other value, then you need to explicitly perform that assignment, which is why your second example works.

Comment: thanks for the response. Anyway to make the delegate] window].rootViewController = 'setter' set the rootViewController to point to the address of _currentViewController (instead of copying over the value of _currentViewController) ?

Comment: You're not copying over the value of anything...as lwburk said above, a pointer only holds a memory address. It's a reference-type. Any number of pointers may point to the same memory address. It's kind of analogous to your physical address: if you write your address on a piece of paper, that's not your house...it just "points" to your house so that I can find it :)

Comment: Although I should say...in computer terms, the memory address is the thing that's being pointed-to, and the pointer is like your "address" in real life. That's probably incredibly confusing.

Comment: Technically, you *are* copying over the value of something. The value is a memory address.